# What to do with shared terms splitting in Wordpress 4.2?

Tags: taxonomy, terms

I read about a possible break compatibility change in Wordpress 4.2 called "shared term splitting".

I download the plugin from jjeaton (https://github.com/jjeaton/wp-find-shared-terms) that show you the shared terms that could affect your installation and here it is a result example.

[image]

Now, what is not really clear is what I have to do before I can safely upgrade my sites to Wordpress 4.2. Can you help me understand?

Comment: It depends entirely on which theme/plugins you're using. So long as none of them rely on/store term ids in their own options, you'll be fine.

Comment: Ok, what should I check in my plugins/theme to be sure they don't rely on terms id?